# Is “Archive.Test.Agent2-9953724-0” a virus or false positive?

Tags: virus, malware, anti-virus

I do a routine scan of my computer every day using ClamXAV. I took a look at the report and it said I had 89 infected items. The infection name is `Archive.Test.Agent2-9953724-0`. The name doesn't sound like a virus.

All of the infected files were things like `setuptools`, `pip`, `wheel` etc… There were apps such as Pycharm and Fusion360. I even had an apple file called `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` flagged. I am using ClamXAV on MacOS Monterey. Are these things false positives or should I be worried?

edit: It was a virus that infected my $PATH.

Comment: Upload it to virustotal https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Comment: Note that ClamAV is notoriously unreliable and this is most likely a false positive https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav/issues/620#issuecomment-1165833526=

Comment: rgb, Could you please expand on your edit: "it was a virus that infected my $PATH"?. Did you manage to get rid of it? I'm seeing this too.

Comment: “It was a virus that infected my $PATH.” What does this mean? macOS is fairly resistant to viruses. And there is no really way to “infect” a $PATH. You might have installed something that would modify your $PATH but also somehow show up as a false positive infection, but editing of $PATH values is normal for many open source packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is a false positive in the ClamAV signature database.

#### The source of the false positive was removed in the daily signature file update as of June 24, 2022.

This seems to be a case of a false positive on the part of ClamAV’s virus signature database as indicated by [this issue post on the official ClamAV GitHub repo](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav/issues/620).

> “This morning we received an update for our signature database from freshclam which includes a signature that leads to many zip files being detected as virus.
>
> The signature is: "Archive.Test.Agent2-9953724-0", which already sounds like it is not a virus.
> On virustotal only ClamAV detects this zip file as virus.
>
> Unfortunately since the zip file contains confidential data I can not post it here.
>
> Please double check with the team responsible for the signature database.”

This is further clarified in [this response here](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav/issues/620#issuecomment-1165790830):

> “The daily database is being republished early and should be out as soon as it can be built and tested. I don't have a specific ETA, but it is already in progress and will be sooner than the normal publishing time.”

And as of [this response two days ago](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav/issues/620#issuecomment-1165833526) (June 24th) the signature file has been updated to remove the false positive:

> “The new daily database update is out and should resolve this issue.”